# When did unpasteurised dairy become illegal in Scotland?

Tags: food, scotland, food-processing

Apparently the sale of raw/unpasteurised dairy in Scotland is fully prohibited.

What legal instrument renders this to be the case, and when was it introduced, and what was the position previously?

Answer (score 5):

It’s only the sale of unpasteurised milk to consumers that’s banned — other dairy products such as cheese may be made from unpasteurised milk. It was banned by the [Milk-based Drinks (Scotland) Regulations 1983 (1983) Statutory Instrument 1983 No. 1514 (S. 138)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1983/1514/contents/made).

Comment: Was it also prohibited prior to the passage of this regulation?

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes, to the best of my knowledge. Press coverage refers to the 1983 regulation as being what banned the sale of unpasteurised milk in Scotland.

Comment: @TylerDurden: It is also apparent from the Hansard debate at the time: https://api.parliament.uk/historic-hansard/commons/1983/nov/16/milk

Comment: @TylerDurden: And confirmed as starting in 1983 by Food Standards Scotland here: https://www.foodstandards.gov.scot/business-and-industry/industry-specific-advice/dairy

Comment: You say “yes, to the best of your knowledge.” But then say that the 1983 was what brought in the ban, an apparent contradiction by which I’m confused. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @TylerDurden Sorry, I misread your question. Unpasteurised milk was not banned prior to 1983.

Comment: @MikeScott ok. But how do you know?